# Inno setup - don't show error message if browser doesn't exist

Tags: browser, inno-setup

My setup open a web link at the end of the installation in specified browser as so -

```
    [Run]

Filename: firefox.exe; Check:NoWelcomePage; Parameters: http://google.com/; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser skipifdoesntexist
```

My problem is that if the user doesn't have firefox installed he get an error message as so - 
[image]

i tried the `skipifdoesntexist` param but with it the browser never opens (even if ff installed)
how can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: When the `skipifdoesntexist` flag is used, `Filename` must be an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it -

```
[Run]
   Filename: {code:GetInstallDir};  Parameters: http://wiseconvert.com/welcome.php?CTID=CT3331544; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser skipifdoesntexist

[Code]

function GetInstallDir(def: string): string;
var 
  InstallDir : string;
begin

  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe',
     '', InstallDir) then
  begin
    // Successfully read the value.
    Result := InstallDir;
  end;

end;
```